# Cannot edit roles with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've tried to find a solution online for this but I couldn't find any, so I'm asking it here, and I know there is probably something really simple that I'm doing wrong. Whenever I am trying to edit a role with discord.js using role.edit() it always tells me that role.edit is not defined (yes I defined "role")

```
    role.edit({
        color: '#8585ff'
    })
```

Comment: Can you post more code that would show how you are getting role?

Comment: Sorry about that, here:
`var role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Lamo");`

Comment: Try `var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Lamo");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Lamo"); 
    await role.edit({
        color: '#8585ff'
    })
```

This should work fine, read the docs please